# Size and offset for plotBackgroundImage in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have some problems positioning the background image in a highcharts chart.

I am trying to achieve this:

[image]

But the problem is that I can not find any way to do that, at least I was not able to find a option in API for offset or width or height for `plotBackgroundImage`.

Now image looks like this:

[image]

and here is the piece of code from inspector:

```
<image
      preserveAspectRatio="none" 
      x="10" 
      y="10" 
      width="260" 
      height="81" 
      xlink:href="http://i1355.photobucket.com/albums/q708/babiidenis/calculator-graph_zps5d26b791.png">
</image>
```

What I want to have is: **x="0" y="0" width="282" height="106"**, it is possible?

**[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v99YX/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you have type with width - for Sure Highcharts won't set higher width than you set for chart width.

In general you haven't disabled margins, set: `margin: [0,0,0,0]`. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/v99YX/1/